# Unable to load .jpg from XAMPP

Tags: php, css, html, xampp, jpeg

I have a simple website, running on XAMPP locally. I am loading many elements from it, including some CSS, some JS, and even a video running in videojs. However when I call this

```
<img class="thumbnail" src="//localhost/xxxx/config/logo.jpg"/>
```

it just gives me the broken image icon. However, when I call it from another website, hosted by someone else, it loads fine. What am i doing wrong here?

edit: these other statements work fine

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//localhost/xxxx/css/bootstrap.css">

<script src="//localhost/xxxx/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you asking if it's valid?

Comment: im suggesting it may not be, in fact i know it's not

Comment: There is a folder between localhost and config, so it's actually //localhost/xxxxx/config/logo.jpg. I didn't include it for personal reasons, nevertheless, the problem still persists.

Comment: broken image icon means the browser cant find the image - the only answer is the src attribute is not correct

Comment: Then why is it that all my CSS and JS sources work fine? I am even able to load a video locally without issues. The only thing not working is images.

Comment: I know it'll sound silly but have you checked if the file exists and it's not corrupted or something like that?

Comment: Not silly. Yes i've checked, and have also changed images a few different times.

Comment: Did you try moving the image to a currently "working" dir, for example, `xxxx/css/` and reference the `img` src from there?

Comment: I just tried, and it still does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Check the file permissions, give yourself full access (read & write).
- Try use the path `/config/logo.jpg`

I've experienced a similar problem with file permissions when I save the image to my localhost directly from another website.